# How angular maps component with url in route?

Tags: angular, serialization, components, router

We know how to configure route in angular4.We studied in angular url represent current state of application.In angular url is serialized form of state.I want to know how this serialization is done in angular internally?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Suraj it's a little unclear what you want to know. However I also happen to be curious about the RouterModule and why Angular uses URLTree's.

I recommend this article from Nate Lapinski which goes into detail:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-routing-series-pillar-1-router-states-and-url-matching-12520e62d0fc

Good luck :-)